# Getting an error file doesn't exist whileit existed

Tags: azure, databricks

When i am using dbutils.fs.ls(/dbfs/mnt/a.parquet) iam not sble to find the file but when i used `dbutils.fs.ls(/mnt/a.parquet)`
I am able to see the path

Do you know the reason?

Answer (score 2):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I got this error**.

[image]

> Note: **Use "dbfs:", not "/dbfs"**: The function does not support the DBFS FUSE mount. This error is caused by passing a path prefixed with "/dbfs"

If you modified the code like this:`dbutils.fs.ls('dbfs:/mnt/a.parquet')` , It will fix your problem:

For the demo, this is my file path: `dbfs:/FileStore/tables/`. As shown in the below image. Now, I am able to see the path

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much but what is the reason behind it

Comment: @Anubhav, when you use `"/dbfs"` as the file path prefix, it indicates that trying to access a file in the DBFS file system using a FUSE mount. However, the function using, `dbutils.fs.ls()`, does not support the use of FUSE mounts.

Comment: To access files in the DBFS file system, you need to use the "dbfs:" prefix instead of "/dbfs".